# C# Selenium 2: make an IList from another IList

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of rows in a table and I want to make another list with certain rows from the first list.

My code is:

```
public IWebElement InvoiceTable { get { return Driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_gvInvoices")); } }
public IList<IWebElement> InvoiceRows { get { return InvoiceTable.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr")); } }
public IList<IWebElement> ACInvoiceRows { get; set; }

public void test()
{
    foreach(IWebElement row in InvoiceRows)
    {
        if(row.Text.Contains("AC"))
        {
            ACInvoiceRows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ACInvoiceRows.Count);
}
```

This throws a `NullReferenceExcpetion`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line, you are not checking to see if `row.Text` is `null` or not.

```
if (row.Text.Contains("AC"))
```

if `row.Text` is `null`, you will end up with a `NullReferenceException`. Do this instead to check for the `null` case.

```
if (row.Text != null && row.Text.Contains("AC"))
```

EDIT:

It's also possible that `ACInvoiceRows` isn't set.  If it's not, you can't use it until you assign an actual object to it, such as:

```
public void test()
{
  //Initiate the collection before using it.
  ACInvoiceRows = new List<IWebElement>();

  foreach(IWebElement row in InvoiceRows)
  {
      if(row.Text.Contains("AC"))
      {
          ACInvoiceRows.Add(row);
      }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(ACInvoiceRows.Count);
}
```

Comment: None of the rows is empty. So that's not an issue (To be sure, I tried your suggestion, but same null pointer exception).

Comment: I didn't say that the row may be empty.  I said the Text property of the row may be empty (null).  However, it may help if you included the stack trace of your exception to narrow down exactly where the null dereference is occurring.

Comment: Its occurring at the ACInvoiceRows.Add(row); line

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, but looks like you cannot create an instance of IwebElement class as its static.

Comment: The statement `new List<IWebElement>()` does not create instances of `IWebElement`.  It only creates a `List` with a `IWebElement` generic argument.  Trust me, it works.

Comment: This is the error I get for that: "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>'
"

Comment: Use `List`, not `IList`.  Do you know the difference between a class and an interface?  You can't create new instances of an interface, but you can create new instances of a class. Your error indicates you are trying to create the interface `IList<T>`. You need to create a new instance of the Class `List<T>`.

Comment: Yes, I was actually gonna come here to post that IList was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you initialized your Driver as following:

```
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
```